# Assign a query to variable to then perform two separate queries?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Is it possible to start an eloquent query, assign it to a variable then continue using the variable for two separate queries without them conflicting with one another. A simple example:

```
$students = $this->student
    // more query stuff
    ->where('is_active', 1);

$bachelorStudents = $students
    ->where('course_id', 3)
    ->get();

$masterStudents = $students
    ->where('course_id', 4)
    ->get();
```

or would I need to do:

```
$bachelorStudents = $this->student
    ->where('course_id', 3)
    ->get();

$masterStudents = $this->student
    ->where('course_id', 4)
    ->get();
```

I always thought I could do the former, but some of my results appear to show I can't but I am open to believe that if you can do it then perhaps I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Why did I get down voted for this question? I'm not saying I shouldn't have, but at least give some explanation so then I can perhaps learn from a mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Once you do that:

```
$students = $this->student->where('is_active', 1);
```

`$stundents` will contain a query builder with your where clause

If you do:

```
$bachelorStudents = $students->where('course_id', 3)->get();
```

You'll add another where clasuse to the `$students` builder, and this should work as you expect

But, when you do:

```
$masterStudents = $students->where('course_id', 4)->get();
```

You are adding another where clasuse to the same `$students` builder, thus resulting the query builder to be something like this:

```
$students->where('is_active', 1)
         ->where('course_id', 3)
         ->where('course_id', 4)
         ->get();
```

That probably isn't what you expect, because you have 2 where clauses with different `course_id` values

Think of `$student` as an object you modify everytime you add a clause, so you can use it for progressive query building, but remember that once you've added a clause to the query builder, the object is modified and the clause will be keept in the builder, so when you re-use the builder it will contain all the clasuses you previously added

Also, Rembember that when you need to apply some pre-defined filters to your query, in Laravel you should use [query scopes](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes)

Comment: So I'd need to do what's in the latter code snippet in my question?

Comment: in this specific case, yes. i suggest you to get a look at [query scopes](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes) that will make you able to apply a default pre-filter to your models (i.e. get all active users), and apply more filter on top of them

Answer (score 1):

When you're calling

```
$students = $this->student->where('is_active', 1);
```

you're creating a query builder object. Calling **where*()** on this object updates the object by adding given criteria. Therefore it's not possible to achieve what you want in your first code snippet, because when you call

```
$masterStudents = $students
  ->where('course_id', 4)
  ->get();
```

the query builder already contains **where('course_id', 3)** constraint added when you **bachelorStudents**.

Comment: So I'd need to do what's in the latter code snippet in my question?

Answer (score 1):

While everyone is explaining query builder and how it works, here's your answer.

1) Start off your [query builder](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_newQuery)

```
$studentsQuery = $this->student
            //Start a new query builder (optional)
            ->newQuery()
            ->where('is_active', 1);
```

2) [Clone](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) the initial query builder to our separate queries

```
$bachelorStudentsQuery = clone $studentsQuery;
$masterStudentsQuery = clone $studentsQuery;
```

3) Assign your `where` conditions and get the results

```
$bachelorStudentsResult = $bachelorStudentsQuery->where('course_id', 3)
                        ->get();

$masterStudentsResult = $masterStudentsQuery->where('course_id',4)
                        ->get();
```

Your use case is too simple for cloning.
It might help you DRY your code when lots of method chaining has been performed, especially when applying filters to queries.